# How many ways can someone choose a permutation $w $ and color each one of the integers [n] so that the minimum element of every cycle of w is white?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

> In how many ways can someone choose a permutation $w \in S_n$ and color each one of the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$ white, yellow or blue so that the minimum element of every cycle of $w$ is white?

*Comments:* I know that the number of permutations  of $[n]$ is $n!$.
I know that there are
$${n \choose a_1,a_2,...,a_r}$$ colorings s.t. exactly $a_i$ elements of $[n]$ are colored with the colour $i$, for $i \in [r]$. For those colours there are $a_i! $ ways to choose a cycle with the color i from w.
(I don't know if any of these is useful)

Answer (score 1):

The unsigned Stirling numbers of first kind ${n\brack k}$ count the number of permutations of $n$ with $k$ disjoint cycles.

Then, the answer is
$$
A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n {n\brack k}3^{n-k}.
$$

To further simplify it, note that the unsigned Stirling numbers of first kind satisfy
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\brack k} x^k = x(x+1)\cdots (x+n-1).
$$

With this in mind, it should be easy to check that
$$
A(n)=(3n-2)!!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(3k-2).
$$

Comment: Can you please explain to me more analytically how you got the sum?

Comment: for each permutation of $1,...,n$ with $k$ disjoint cycles, we need to color in white the $k$ elements of $\{1,...,n\}$ which are the lowest of their cycle, and we have $3$ choices of colors for each of the other $n-k$ elements of $\{1,...,n\}$, for a total of $3^{n-k}$ choices of coloring for each permutation. Summing over all permutations gives $A(n)=\sum_{w\in S_n} 3^{n-k}$ where $k$ is the number of cycles in $w$. Transform this into a sum over $k$ using the definition I recalled of Stirling numbers and you should be done.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you!